# What's the flink ReduceFunction's default trigger?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

And what's the difference about WindowFunction's trigger and ReduceFunction's trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "ReduceFunction Trigger" or "WindowFunction Trigger" because triggers and functions are orthogonal. In Flink, a window operation consists of at least three parts:

- `WindowAssigner`: The window assigner decides for each records into which window(s) it is assigned.
- `Function`: The function(s) of a window process the records that are assigned to a window. Functions can be a `ReduceFunction`, `AggregateFunction`, `WindowFunction`, or `ProcessWindowFunction`. `ReduceFunction` and `AggregateFunction` can be eagerly applied before all records have been received. This is beneficial because the amount of data to store in the state of a window can be significantly reduced that way. `WindowFunction` and `ProcessWindowFunction` process all records that are collected by the window. It is also possible to combine an eager function (`ReduceFunction`, `AggregateFunction`) and a full window function (`WindowFunction`, `ProcessFunction`). In this case, the records are eagerly aggregated and the eager aggregation result is eventually given to the full window function.
- `Trigger`: A `Trigger` decides when to emit a result from and/or discard the state of a window operation.

A `ReduceFunction` is always immediately applied when a new record is added to the window. The result of the window is emitted when the `Trigger` of the window fires.

Comment: How eager aggregation is implemented？ Could you give me a ref about that?

Comment: You can do that with a `Trigger` that fires and thereby Acauses the window to emit a result, but does not remove the state of the window. At a later point in time the `Trigger` can fire again and update the previously emitted result.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers apply only to windows. ReduceFunction doesn't need a trigger, it is a transform operation, that calls `processElement()` at each new element.

In short:

`ReduceFunction` triggers at every element (similar to `onElement()` window trigger).

`WindowFunction` triggers (by default) on time (event, processing or ingestion). But it is flexible regarding this aspect and accepts custom triggers.

More on triggers:

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#triggers

Default reduce implementation:

https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/operators/StreamGroupedReduce.java

Comment: Can you give me a ref to the code about ReduceFunction default trigger?